# Optional delegate method not optional

Tags: swift, delegates, option-type

I have this class `apiHandler` with the following delegate methods:

```
@objc protocol apiHandlerDelegate: class {
    @objc optional func didGetMessages(_ sender:apiHandler)
    @objc optional func didGetEvents(_ sender:apiHandler)
    @objc optional func didLogin(success:Bool, sender:apiHandler)
}
```

One of my `viewControllers` depends on `didGetEvents` so I do

```
class myViewController: UIViewController, apiHandlerDelegate
```

Now, somehow, in `myViewController`, I also need to implement

```
func didLogin(success: Bool, sender: apiHandler) {
    // do nothing
}
```

Otherwise the app will crash, returning

> [myApp. myViewController didLoginWithSuccess:sender:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x7f90ac01b410'

Do I misunderstand the Optional part? I want to be able to just implement those delegate methods that are needed for my viewController

EDIT//////

So, in my apiHandler, I make a REST call, and in the completion block I call didLogin as such:

```
let urlString = String(format:"%@/api/sessions/current", baseUrl)
                    Alamofire.request(urlString, headers: headers)
                        .responseJSON { response in
                            self.Login(completion: { (success) in
                                self.delegate?.didLogin!(success: success, sender: self)
                                completion(true)
                            })
                    }
```

Of importance to know is:
1) **didGetMessages** and **didGetEvents** behave optionally, i.e. I don't need to implement them in the viewControllers that are a delegate to the apiHandler
2) didLogin somehow NEEDS to be implemented otherwise the app crashes

The major difference between 1) and 2) is that didLogin has a completion block. I need to have the boolean value in my ViewControllers

Comment: How are you presenting the viewcontrollers?

Comment: @AngryWarden Just from a TabViewController

Comment: Why would you call `apiHandlerDelegate` on `myViewController` if you are "doing nothing" on `didLogin`. It's unclear what you asking

Comment: @AngryWarden, in that specific ViewController, I DO need one of the other delegate methods

Comment: Aha, so without calling `didLogin` on that viewcontroller is not possible and will cause a crash?

Comment: @AngryWarden, that's correct

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error.

Comment: Somewhere in your code, you must have a code calling `didLogin(success:sender:)`. Please find it (or them?) and show us the code. You need to fix that part.

Comment: @OOPer: see my edit

Comment: @Sjakelien, the problem seems to be very clear. `didLogin!` means _Please crash my app, when `didLogin` is not implemented_. Better avoid `!`.

Answer (score 2):

I think If you call `didLoginWithSuccess` from Swift code for optional functions you need use optional chaining:

```
apiHandler.didLoginWithSuccess?()
```

If you call `didLoginWithSuccess` from Objective-C code, you need to check is object responds to a given selector:

```
if ([apiHandler respondsToSelector:@selector(didLoginWithSuccess:)])
{
    // then call func
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may need to change this line:

```
self.delegate?.didLogin!(success: success, sender: self)
```

To:

```
self.delegate?.didLogin?(success: success, sender: self)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily make it optional by doing the following without any objectiveC code:

```
protocol apiHandlerDelegate: class {
    func didGetMessages(_ sender:apiHandler)
    func didGetEvents(_ sender:apiHandler)
    func didLogin(success:Bool, sender:apiHandler)
}

extension apiHandlerDelegate {
    func didGetMessages(_ sender:apiHandler) { } // Empty implementation to make it optional
    func didGetEvents(_ sender:apiHandler) { } // Empty implementation to make it optional
    func didLogin(success:Bool, sender:apiHandler) { } // Empty implementation to make it optional
}
```

For more information, please check out this link: https://medium.com/@ant_one/how-to-have-optional-methods-in-protocol-in-pure-swift-without-using-objc-53151cddf4ce

Answer (score 1):

> Do I misunderstand the Optional part? I want to be able to just implement those delegate methods that are needed for my viewController

As it relates to protocols, `optional` just means that the compiler won't insist that classes that adopt the protocol implement those methods. By contrast, the compiler will emit an error if you fail to implement methods marked `required`.

However, if your code tries to call an `optional` method that hasn't been implemented, you'll get the unimplemented selector run-time error that you're seeing here. If you create a protocol with `optional` methods, you should check that an object implements that method before you call it, like:

```
if someObject.responds(to:Selector("didLoginSuccess:sender:") {
    someObject.didLogin(success:... sender:...)
}
```

In other words, the compiler won't prevent you from *calling* an optional method; it's up to you to make sure that optional methods that you call actually exist.